# JavaScript Architecture for non-SPA

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, knockout.js, frontend

I was wondering what's the best approach to use Backbone.js (or other MV* JS framework) without rewriting my whole application into a Single Page Application. I just want to handle my CRUD operations with JS and my API, but retaining my old navigation links.

If the user navigates to /venues, he can do CRUD related to venues without leaving the page.

I guess it's like having many SPA.

How I can modularize Backbone (or any other JS framework) so I can trigger only the module I need on each page.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I use backbone like this in a lot of different cases. I end up:

- **Ignore the Router**
- **Views and modules are just JS dictionaries with some built in useful methods**
- **Collections are beefed up arrays**

After that, just write some javascript!

Comment: Not a bad way to look at it, but surely ignoring the router is ignoring an extremely useful tool for creating a really slick UI.

Comment: True. But for providing structure to CRUD operations, I would hold off on introducing a router to start.

Comment: Maybe we are using routers/views differently, but I think that a router could really help with CRUD. For example if you have a  `CreateView` and an `UpdateView`, having a router that has a `#/create` and `#/update` route that deal with replacing the content on the page with each of these views, could surely only help with structure!

Answer (score 1):

I have used an approach similar to @dormisher.

#### Option 1

Create a `MyApplication` object with placeholder objects for your Models, Views, etc:

```
var MyApplication = {
  Models: {},
  Views: {},
  Collections: {},
  Routers: {},
  initFirstApp: function() {
    new MyApplication.Routers.FirstRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
  },
  initSecondApp: function() {
    // similar to above...
  }
};
```

Define your Models, Views, etc. by extending the `MyApplication` object:

```
var MyApplication.Routers.FirstRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({ ... });
```

Then, assuming you have a js file that's only loaded when you want your FirstApp to run, just call `MyApplication.initFirstApp()`.

(Of course you could also organize your Backbone constructs by application, as @dormisher's code sample shows, and give each one an `init` or `start` method.)

#### Option 2

Another option is to have one common router which you can instantiate on every Backbone-driven page and Backbone will automatically take over if the current url matches a defined route. I recommend you only use this approach if there is only one route for each page (i.e. each application is a SPA and there are no sub-routes).

Answer (score 0):

I have used this approach in a few applications, I am rewriting a section of a site at the moment and creating many a small backbone application for each main navigation section of the site.

It seems obvious but all I have done is have a single script file for each section. So for the users section of the site I simple have a js file called `users.js`, that contains all my views/models/routers etc that are used for this section. Anything that is shared like base views or whatever go in a shared js file that is included along with the `users.js` file. This way everything is kept together and easy to find, and your only making a couple of requests to the server on page load.

To improve organisation I also store everything in a namespace-like JSON object, so I create a global JSON object like so:

```
var MyApplication = {
  Users: {
    Views: {}, // all backbone views go in here
    Models: {} // all models go here
    // routers etc
  }
}
```

Simple really, but you know the old axim: Keep It Simple Stupid!

Comment: I thought about that. But: how do you initialize each module/app for each section? I intend to serve one minified production JS file.

Comment: I do it in a script at the bottom of the first page that is loaded for each section. Usually it is a case of simply instantiating a router, which then set's up all the required views etc in it's `initialize` method.

I would probably steer away from a single minified js file in this case as it will be full of unnecessary and irrelevant code. You could create a minified js file per section that contains everything you need. What server framework / tech are you using?